# Possible loss of precision in java declaring bytes

Tags: java, byte, precision

I'm currently attempting to write a serial implementation of MODbus in java. The main problem I'm having is that when I declare a byte (or short for that matter) as something like 0xC4 (for a byte) I get a "Loss of precision error".

Is there someway around this? Or am I forced to treat all numeric types like their 1 bit shorter then they really are (ala 7bit, 15 bit, 31 bit, 63 bit)?

And example:

```
 byte[] test = 
    {
        0x11,
        0x02,
        0x00,
        0xC4,
        0x00,
        0x16
    };
```

This throws a warning on 0xC4 that "Possible loss of precision" required byte, found int.

Comment: Show the small piece of code where you get the warning

Comment: Updated to show example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `0xC4`, that is an integer literal that is bigger than the [maximum value for a `byte`, 127](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#MAX_VALUE), so you must explicitly cast it to a `byte`.

Try

```
byte[] test = 
{
    0x11,
    0x02,
    0x00,
    (byte) 0xC4,
    0x00,
    0x16
};
```